# What's the purpose of using 2 Schottky diodes connected in such way?

Tags: diodes

This is how the 2 Schottky diodes are connected:

[image]

Why is it?

Comment: What is to the right ?  What is the part number?

Comment: A BAT54 can be got in a SOT23 package as a dual diode. If you only need to use one diode, then the other is not used.

Comment: @Kartman thank you for answer. In general, what's the purpose of using dual diodes, such as BAT54?

Comment: If the board already used a BAT54C, it is much more economical en masse to re-use an existing part than to spec, BOM, order, receive, store, provision pick-and-place machine for another part, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second diode's anode is not connected, and that diode has no effect. This is essentially just a single diode.

In this circuit, there is no difference compared to the single BAT54. The dual BAT54C was probably chosen because it is already used somewhere else in the circuit, or because it is a standard part.

Answer (score 3):

D804 is a part that contains two diodes, but as others said, only one is used. Search for it and you will probably find it has been used elsewhere on the same circuit, and it is cheaper to just use the same part rather than go with a single diode. If this is the only instance it is used, it could be that it is avaiable at a cheap rate at the assembly house they used. This was why I used this part in one of my projects, only connecting one diode.

For completeness, why is this one diode connected there? When the relay coil is activated, the diode does nothing. However, when you go to turn the relay coil off to shut off the relay, the inductance of the coil will react to the change in current by raising the voltage in such a way that current continuous flowing through the same path. This can damage the system, so a diode is inserted which allows the current to flow through, getting dissipated by the voltage drop across both the coil and diode, without damaging the system.